# failure/error expect(response).to render_template( index ) nomethoderror:assert_template has been extracted to a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe StaticPagesController, :type => :controller do
  context "GET #index" do
    before do
      get :index
    end

    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    it "renders the index template" do
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
  end

end
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is pretty self explanatory.

`assigns` and `assert_template` have been extracted out of `rails` to a seperate `rails-controller-testing` gem. Have you added that gem to your `Gemfile`?

Refert to [rails-controller-testing](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing) for more info.

Comment: I add 'gem 'rails-controller-testing'' but not working

Comment: thanks I fixed,But I get a new error.How to send pic?

Comment: You could update the question or close the current question and start a new question.

Comment: how to close question?I already asked another question.My first time use this site not sure how

Comment: Closing the question is nothing but accepting the answer if it answers the question.